# What to add as "measure" to a linestringM in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring, st-makeline

I am kind of new into the GIS world. I have a couple of GPS data in a CSV file as LonLat coordinates.

I used PostGIS to create points from those coordinates using `ST_MakePoint()`.
Then I tried to recreate the route of those points using the `ST_MakeLine()` function. The output of the function is of geometry type `Linestring`.

So, I used a repository to map match the recreated route to the real routes on a map. However, that repository requires you to use geometry of type `LinestringM`. I come upon this post: [Adding M coordinate with different measurings in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139987/adding-m-coordinate-with-different-measurings-in-postgis) and it says to use the function `ST_AddMeasure()` to create the M dimension.

My question is: What do you use as dimension M? Do you use the length of the linestring between each GPS point? Can you use timestamp as a form of measurement? Is it any arbitrary measurement you want to define?

Comment: There are two restrictions: M values need to be numeric, and they need to be strictly increasing over the course of a geometry. And indeed you would usually add the UNIX timestamp of your GPS positions to feed to any map matching suite; use `ST_MakePointM` to create them. Also, I'd be interested what repo you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The repo I am using is this one [pgMapMatch](https://github.com/amillb/pgMapMatch). I am still not sure what to use as dimension M for the linestringMs. I used the ST_length for every linestring but as you said, it needs to be of increasing order. I am wondering if it is a necessary dimension.